# When I access my Website with Safari, Google Analytics shows referrers as "Direct", why?

Tags: google-analytics, referrer, safari

When I access my Website (website A) with Safari (v 10.1.1) via a link from another website (website B), the access (in the real-time section) is seen as direct access.

With firefox, I can properly see the referrer (website B), why?

A couple of notes:

1. Before doing the test, I deleted all the cookies
2. The link in Website B to my website didn't contain the `noreferrer` attribute

Comment: This seems to have happened before, in mobile Safari specifically. It was also supposedly resolved by Apple's developers. I wonder if it's rearing its head again: https://searchengineland.com/mobile-safari-searchers-referrer-google-162066

Comment: Check with different versions of Safari in order to determinate if the problem is the version (see comment before) or is elsewhere.

Comment: I can't check with other versions on Mac OS but I've checked with Safari on iOS and it seems it works fine. Can we assume it was a Safari bug?

Comment: I've made some more tests: it seems that for some Web sites it works, for some others it doesn't. When I said Safari on iOS worked, I tested with Facebook as referrer ... but then I realized that FB worked also on Safari on Mac OS.... Quora, instead, didn't work (both in iOS and Mac OS) while it works on Firefox. Any clue?

Comment: Tested with Safari 11.1.2 (Mac OS): same thing: with Quora, for example, the referrer is not set.

Comment: Is your website HTTPS?

Comment: yes, it is HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

By Direct google Analytics means that user "Entered your website in address bar to access you website".

Because "Referral" section shows the reason your user is here. Like I go to Google and search BBC, so the Google analytics will show Google as referral. If i directly search BBC in the address bar and access it the Referral will show it as "DIRECT"

If "Direct" is showing in your Web Browser list, then it means Safari is providing good security and privacy.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Mobile Safari doesn’t support the “meta referrer” tag.
Source: https://searchengineland.com/mobile-safari-searchers-referrer-google-162066

Comment: The OP appears to be referring to both Safari Desktop and Safari Mobile.